# automatically logoff interactive user sessions for workgroup windows servers

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, elastic-beanstalk

I have windows application servers that are not domain joined and any changes I make to them must be doable via a locally run script (not a remote command) that is executed when they are provisioned or deployed to (they are in an elastic beanstalk).

Is there a command I can run that enables this policy or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. However, you can logoff specific sessions with the 'logoff' command. You can query for sessions with the 'query session' command.

More information here and an example script can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/259436/how-to-log-off-all-terminal-server-session-users-from-a-command-prompt